# Error while saving file in magento Grid/From

Tags: forms, magento, grid

i'm workin on a new Grid for my **magento** admin Module and i've added this field in the From to upload a file
 or an image :

```
$fieldset->addField('type_prev', 'file',
     array(
         'label' => 'Preview',
          'required' => false,
          'name' => 'type',
      ));
```

But in my controller when i try to get the value of :

```
Zend_Debug::dump($_FILES['type_prev']);
```

i got this Error : Notice: Undefined index: type_prev...

all the other fields are workin well !

this is my form declaration :

```
    protected function _prepareForm()
    {
         $form = new Varien_Data_Form(
                array(
                  'id' => 'edit_form',
                  'action' => $this->getUrl('*/*/save', array('id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('id'))
                     ),
                 'method' => 'post',
                 'enctype'   => 'multipart/form-data'
                 )
              );
      $form->setUseContainer(true);
      $this->setForm($form);
      return parent::_prepareForm();
   }
```

can you help please ?

thx

Comment: forgot to add enctype= multipart/form-data to your form ?

Comment: there is no need to : http://www.excellencemagentoblog.com/magento-admin-form-field

Comment: are you sure ? For example, i can see one in app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Customer/Edit/Form.php .. you should give it a try

Comment: i got it already in my form declaration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i just changed the name and the id to "preview" and it works !

```
$fieldset->addField('preview', 'file',
            array(
                'label' => 'Preview',
                'required' => false,
                'name' => 'preview',
```

thx !                 ));

Answer (score 0):

Try this (using the name attribute):

```
Zend_Debug::dump($_FILES['type']);
```